# How can I make my canvas (chart.js) to resize on different devices?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I have a `canvas`:

```
<canvas id="chart1" width="1000" height="250"></canvas>
```

But on my mobile, it expands.
[See screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFQ17.jpg)

I tried on making the `width="100%"` but it makes them smaller.

```
<canvas id="chart1" width="100%" height="250"></canvas>
```

My mobile [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAIV3.jpg).

```
var ctx = $('#sht1_chart').get(0).getContext('2d');
var sht1Chart = new Chart(ctx).Line({
  labels: [],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Temperature (Celsius)",
      fillColor: "rgba(63,63,191,0.2)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(63,63,191,1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(63,63,191,1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(63,63,191,1)",
      data: []
    },
    {
      label: "Humidity (%)",
      fillColor: "rgba(63,191,191,0.2)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(63,191,191,1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(63,191,191,1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(63,191,191,1)",
      data: []
    }
  ]
});
```

### Update

It is in a container, btw.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        HOT SPOT 1 (Location: Extreme West Middle)
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Temperature: <span id='temp1_value'></span>
        Humidity: <span id='hum1_value'>
        </p>
        <canvas id='sht1_chart' height='250'></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS doesn't seem to work?

```
#canvas  {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

Comment: try max-width:1000px , width:100% with css

Answer (score 0):

### Check parent container

`width: 100%` should work just fine. Check the parent container to make sure that it's `width` is set correctly.

### Use `vw` units

If you are looking to try another solution, try using the `vw` units to set the width. Each `1vw` is equal to 1% of the viewport window. `width: 100vw` would set the chart to 100% of the viewport, but since it's in a container, `100vw` is probably to wide, so play with the value.

> **Note:** You can learn more about the `vw` unit from [W3 CSS Units](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp).